# How can I get content using XML::Twig?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

My aim is that `start_tag_handler` (see below) get the `apps`/`title` content when it finds an `apps`/`title` tag (see sample XML below).

And
`end_tag_handler` gets the `apps`/`logs` content when it finds an `apps`/`logs` tag.

But instead this code returns null and exits.

#### This is the Perl code for parsing (using [XML::Twig](http://www.xmltwig.com/xmltwig/))###:

```
    #!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

    use XML::Twig;
    my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
                start_tag_handlers =>
                  { 'apps/title' => \&kicks
                  },
                twig_roots =>
                  { 'apps' => \&app
                  },
                end_tag_handlers =>
                  { 'apps/logs' => \&bye
                  }
                );
    $twig -> parsefile( "doc.xml");

    sub kicks {
        my ($twig, $elt) = @_;
        print "---kicks--- \n";
        print $elt -> text;
        print " \n";
    }

    sub app {
        my ($twig, $apps) = @_;
        print "---app--- \n";
        print $apps -> text;
        print " \n";
    }


    sub bye {
        my ($twig, $elt) = @_;
        print "bye \n";
        print $elt->text;
        print " \n";
    }
```

#### This is doc.xml###:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <auto>
      <apps>
        <title>watch</title>
        <commands>set,start,00:00,alart,end</commands>
        <logs>csv</logs>
      </apps>
      <apps>
        <title>machine</title>
        <commands>down,select,vol_100,check,line,end</commands>
        <logs>dump</logs>
      </apps>
    </auto>
```

#### This is the output in the console###:

```
    C:\>perl parse.pl
    ---kicks---

    ---app---
    watchset,start,00:00,alart,endcsv
    ---kicks---

    ---app---
    machinedown,select,vol_100,check,line,enddump
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the `XML::Twig` documentation for [`start_tag_handlers`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/Twig.pm#start_tag_handlers):

> The handlers are called with 2 params: the twig and the element. The element is empty at that point, its attributes are created though.

At the time `start_tag_handlers` is called, the text content isn't even seen yet, since parsing of the *start tag* (e.g. `<title>`, not the end tag `</title>`) has only just completed.

The reason that `end_tag_handlers` don't supply element text is probably for symmetry :-).

What you want is probably to use `twig_handlers` instead:

```
my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        'apps/title' => \&kicks,
        'apps/logs' => \&bye
    },
    twig_roots => {
        'apps' => \&app
    },
);
```

Output is:

```
---kicks--- 
watch 
bye 
csv 
---app--- 
watchset,start,00:00,alart,endcsv
---kicks--- 
machine 
bye 
dump 
---app--- 
machinedown,select,vol_100,check,line,enddump
```

Comment: Thank you very much,I will try your idea then will comment more.  
And I misunderstand XML::Twig documentation,I thought start_tag_handlers knew it at that point...

Comment: twig_handlers are the usual way of calling handlers, start_tag_handlers should be used only when using twig_handlers is not possible (the element is potentially too big for example). end_tag_handlers should be used even less, as mentioned in the docs.

Comment: It was works !  
Wow,author. I will do perusal.-> To mirod.  
Thanks a lot and little suprised by comment from author.